# Can we deploy Two Kinesis Firehose Delivery Stream's in Single Cloud formation Template. If yes, How?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis-firehose

1. I am able deploy only one delivery stream using CFN. Having two Kinesis firehose delivery stream. Is there any alternate way to accomplish two Kinesis firehose in single template. Thanks !!

   ```
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
    Resources:

    ##Kinesis Firehose1
    DeliveryStreamLogGroup:   ## Cloudwatch log group
       Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup 
       Properties:
        LogGroupName: ----

    DeliveryStreamLogStreamS3: # Cloudwatch log stream
      Type: AWS::Logs::LogStream
      Properties:
        LogGroupName: ---
        LogStreamName: ---

    DeliveryStreamLogStreamRedshift:
      Type: AWS::Logs::LogStream
      Properties:
        LogGroupName: ---
        LogStreamName: ---

    DeliveryStream:
     Type: AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream
     DependsOn: RedshiftCluster
     Properties:
     DeliveryStreamName: ---
     DeliveryStreamType: ---
     RedshiftDestinationConfiguration: ---
   ```

   ##Kinesis Firehose2
   DeliveryStreamLogGroup:
   Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
   Properties:
   LogGroupName: ----

   ```
    DeliveryStreamLogStreamS3:
      Type: AWS::Logs::LogStream
      Properties:
        LogGroupName: ---
        LogStreamName: ---

    DeliveryStreamLogStreamRedshift:
      Type: AWS::Logs::LogStream
      Properties:
        LogGroupName: ---
       LogStreamName: ---

    DeliveryStream:
      Type: AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream
      DependsOn: RedshiftCluster
      Properties:
         DeliveryStreamName: ---
         DeliveryStreamType: ---
         RedshiftDestinationConfiguration: ---
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can. Just give different names to your delivery stream resources

```
DeliveryStream1:
   Type: AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream
   DependsOn: RedshiftCluster1
   Properties:
      DeliveryStreamName: ---
      DeliveryStreamType: ---
      RedshiftDestinationConfiguration: ---
DeliveryStream2:
   Type: AWS::KinesisFirehose::DeliveryStream
   DependsOn: RedshiftCluster2
   Properties:
      DeliveryStreamName: ---
      DeliveryStreamType: ---
      RedshiftDestinationConfiguration: ---
```

"Type" attribute defines what kind of resource you want to create. You can create multiple resources of same type provided you gave different name to each resource of same type